# how to merge one row data to one column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

i have one trigger like this:

```
alter trigger newTrigger
on table2
after insert 
as
begin
    declare @rowData nvarchar(max)
    if exists(select * from inserted)
    begin
        Set @rowData = (select * from inserted)
    end

    insert into table1(rowData, date)
    values(@rowData, getdate())
end
```

i want after insert into table2, the inserted record and date insert to table1
but i cant merge the data of row into one column!

```
------------------table2--------------------
id   |  name  |   lname  | birth
1        j          jj       2000-03-03


-------------------table1 after insert into table2 -----------------
rowData            |     date
a,j,jj,2000-03-03       2017-05-07
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the conversion and add one by one each column

eg:

```
Set @rowData = (select cast(col1 as varchar(10)) + cast(col2 as varchar(10)) from inserted)
```

for your edit with the col names. If the column already is varchar, the only that you have to take care is to avoid the length overflow :

```
Set @rowData = (select cast((id + ',' + name + ',' + lname + ',' + cast(birth as varchar(12)) ) as varchar(4000))  from inserted)
```